# Adding quotes to an output in python

Tags: python-3.x, variables, quotes

I am trying print the final output in single quotes, but unable to figure out how to do so. Kinda new to python, so any guidance to get me on the right track would be helpful.

I have tried concatenating quotes with the variable in the print function but getting 'invalid syntax' errors

```
sample = []
while True:
    print ('Enter items into this list or blank + enter to stop')
    name=input()
    if name == '':
        break
    sample = sample + [name]
print(sample)

sample.insert(len(sample)-1, 'and')
print(sample)

print('Here is the final output:')
print(*sample, sep = ", ")
```

The final output shows something like which is fine:
A, B, C, and, D

However, the desired output is:
'A, B, C, and, D'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about joining the list to a string beforehand using `join`, and then using that string in print via `string.format` or `f-string`

```
print('Here is the final output:')
print(sample)
s = ', '.join(sample).strip()
print(f"'{s}'")
```

The output will be

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'and', 'D']
Here is the final output:
'A, B, C, and, D'
```

`f-string` for python3.6

```
s = ', '.join(sample).strip()

print(f"'{s}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

escape the quotes like below

```
print('\'hello world\'')
```

Or use the double quotes

```
print("'hello world'")
```

Comment: although this works for simple use case, I don't think OP is stuck at that level.